# Neo4j Cant find neo4j-shell tool on Windows v2.1.2 Community Edition

Tags: neo4j

I can't find the neo4j-shell after installing the community edition on Windows. Am I missing something. I wanted to use it to run in a batch of cypher statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Version 2.2.0 in Windows, go to the Neo4j Community Launcher, then click options, click on Command Line tools/ Command Prompt, then type Neo4jShell. You can paste sequences of queries into the shell, very convenient to load a series of CSV imports for instance..

Answer (score 1):

Install the binary from here: http://www.neo4j.org/download/other_versions

Then navigate to the bin folder and run Neo4jShell.bat.